# How to set target in typescript to fromEvent() in rxjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors, rxjs

I'm using '[`rxjs`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com)' library alongside typescript.
Issue is, I can't figure out how to pass a **simple button to [`fromEvent()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEvent) from rxjs**

Trying this makes the compiler complain:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as rx from 'rxjs';

const RXComponent: React.FC = () => {

    rx.fromEvent(document.getElementById('dblbutton'), 'click')

    return (
        <form>
            <input type='button' id='dblbutton' value='Click me!'>
            </input>
        </form>
    )
}

export default RXComponent;
```

This throws the following exception:

> Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'FromEventTarget'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to
>   type 'FromEventTarget'.  TS2345

[image]

I tried to change the definition to a node-list as per documentation:

> List of DOM Nodes, returned for example by document.querySelectorAll
>   or Node.childNodes.
>
> Although this collection is not event target in itself, fromEvent will
>   iterate over all Nodes it contains and install event handler function
>   in every of them. When returned Observable is unsubscribed, function
>   will be removed from all Nodes.

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('#dblbutton')
const obs = rx.fromEvent(btn, 'click')
obs.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

Which technically works and stops the compiler from complaining, but if I open the actual website on localhost I just get bunch of errors referencing the library.

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, you just need to coerce (or cast) type explicitly, so I made a little helper for this

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs'
import { FromEventTarget } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/fromEvent'

const
    mkEventTarget = (qs: string): FromEventTarget<Event> =>
        document.querySelector (qs) as FromEventTarget<Event>

  , evClicks: Rx.Observable<Event> = Rx.fromEvent (mkEventTarget ("#btn"), "click")

evClicks.subscribe (() => console.log ("Test"))
```

Comment: Also, you may want to get this element on componentDidMount () cuz it doesn't exist before

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something like this using `refs` callback pattern which passes you actual element reference, see if that works for you:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as rx from 'rxjs';

const RXComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const buttonHandler = (buttonRef) => rx.fromEvent(buttonRef, 'click')

    return (
        <form>
            <input
               type='button'
               id='dblbutton'
               value='Click me!'
               ref={buttonHandler}>
            </input>
        </form>
    )
}

export default RXComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to use type assertion like `event.target as HTMLInputElement` every time you access the target of the event in RxJS with TypeScript, you can create a more specific event stream that automatically treats each event as having an `HTMLInputElement` as its target. This approach involves defining a custom type for the event handler and then using that in your `fromEvent` call.

Here’s an example of how you can do this:

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

const inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('myInput');

// Define a specific event type
type InputEvent = Event & {
  target: HTMLInputElement;
};

const inputEvent$ = fromEvent<InputEvent>(inputElement, 'input');

inputEvent$.subscribe({
  next: (event) => {
    // Now you can directly use `event.target.value` without additional assertion
    console.log(event.target.value);
  },
  error: (err) => console.error(err),
  complete: () => console.log('Completed'),
});
```

In this code, `InputEvent` is a type that extends the standard `Event` type, specifying that `target` is an `HTMLInputElement`. This allows you to use `event.target` directly as an `HTMLInputElement` within your `subscribe` block, eliminating the need for repetitive type assertions.